# (ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm using library to make expandable tableview
 this is the library

https://github.com/wannabegeek/ExpandableTableView

what i want to do is changing row height for children rows
 but

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForSection:(NSUInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

never called

i uncommented them from delegate class

what shall i do?

Comment: Post some of your code so we can see if you've left something out

Comment: did you set datasource and delegate in your tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all

solved

implement this method in expandableTableView.m

https://github.com/jasonparekh/ExpandableTableView/commit/7eccd302a2edb42d950bed58de0657a0e16f1bd8

then this methods are called

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom delegates :

Step 1: Uncomment these lines in **ExpandableTableViewDelegate.h**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForSection:(NSUInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Step 2: add following lines into **ExpandableTableView.h**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForSection:(NSUInteger)section;
```

Step 3: add following lines into **ExpandableTableView.m**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForSection:(NSUInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}
```

Step 4: Now add following lines into to your **ExampleController.m**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100; //return custom height value
} 

- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForSection:(NSUInteger)section;
{
    return 100; //return custom height value
}
```

Comment: yes thanks , this code will work but i found another one in the library i posted the answer in a reply

Answer (score 0):

The delegate methods

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForSection:(NSUInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

are never get called because they have not implemented them.

See - [ExpandableTableView](https://github.com/wannabegeek/ExpandableTableView/blob/master/ExpandableTableView/Control/ExpandableTableViewDelegate.h) line 22,23

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the link you provided for the library, it seems as if the author has commented out and not implemented those methods from the delegate. Some of the comments on his site are people telling him they need to implement those methods themselves but are unable to.

```
@protocol ExpandableTableViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView willExpandSection:(NSUInteger)section;
- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView didExpandSection:(NSUInteger)section;
- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView willContractSection:(NSUInteger)section;
- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView didContractSection:(NSUInteger)section;

- (BOOL)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView canRemoveSection:(NSUInteger)section;

//- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForSection:(NSUInteger)section;
//- (CGFloat)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forSection:(NSUInteger)section;
```